# Update query inserts null in rows which are not mentioned for the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This is my update query

```
UPDATE customer_entity_varchar
    SET value = (case when attribute_id = 5 then '$fname'
                         when attribute_id = 6 then '$mname'
                         when attribute_id = 7 then '$lname'
                    end)
where entity_id='$entityId'
```

This query works abnormally it does inserts value for attribute_id with values 5,6,7 but I have more attribute_id each with a different value in the "value" column. When I fire the above query it makes all the values corresponding to all other attribute_id = NULL. I don't want that! I want all other attribute_id values to remain untouched. How do I achieve this?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `else` statement in your `case` statement:

```
UPDATE customer_entity_varchar
SET value = (case when attribute_id = 5 then '$fname'
                  when attribute_id = 6 then '$mname'
                  when attribute_id = 7 then '$lname'
                  else value
             end)
where entity_id='$entityId'
```

---

Or you can use `where` criteria.

```
UPDATE customer_entity_varchar
SET value = (case when attribute_id = 5 then '$fname'
                  when attribute_id = 6 then '$mname'
                  when attribute_id = 7 then '$lname'
             end)
where entity_id='$entityId' and attribute_id in (5,6,7)
```

Comment: Thank you.. please bear with me i will try it out n get back to u in a minute

Answer (score 0):

If an else is not provided in a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression, NULL is used.

> If there was no matching result value, the result after ELSE is
>   returned, or NULL if there is no ELSE part.

Answer (score 0):

In your where statement add:

```
AND attribute_id IN (5,6,7)
```